# If a key dont exist in array how can I ignore the error

Tags: php

I need some help with an array. I run a web based game where I need to give some values a short description. This works with no problem as long as the key exists in the array, if theres a key that the user has that is not in the array it outputs `Undefined offset` errors. There are some keys that wont be in the array, but how can i ignore them and not print errors?

```
$storage_values = array(35000 => "Använde sin list och besegrade Ahmaroth", 
                        71503 => "Avslutade uppgiften att dräpa 250 vargar", 
                        56431 => "Avslutade uppgiften att dräpa 300 drakar", 
                        and alot more);

$storage = $db->query("SELECT `key` FROM user_storage WHERE userid = 69")->fetch();


<? if (array_key_exists($storage['key'], $storages)): ?>

<? foreach($db->query("SELECT `key`, `date` FROM user_storage WHERE user_id = 69") as $row): ?>

<tr>
<td>Date</td>
<td><?=$storages[$row['key']]?></td>
</tr>

<? endforeach ?>
<? endif ?>
```

Now if theres a key in user_storage which does not exist in the array I get offset error, how can I ignore them, and only print out the ones that exist in the array?

I have tried adding a @ before $storages[$row['key']], that removes the offset error but it still print out empty `<td>` element

I hope you understand and thanks in advance.

Comment: Are those really _errors_ you get? I would expect that to be notices or warnings. Anyway, for production you certainly should turn off error display in your php settings. Nevertheless you should fix your code to be more robust.

Comment: Can it be that there is a confusion with the variable names for `$storage_values` and `$storages`?

Answer (score 0):

with something like

```
if(isset($storages[$row['key']])){ ?>
   <tr>
   <td>Date</td>
   <td><?=$storages[$row['key']]?></td>
   </tr>
<?php }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below code

```
<? if (array_key_exists($storage['key'], $storages)): ?>
  <? foreach($db->query("SELECT `key`, `date` FROM user_storage WHERE user_id = 69") as $row): ?>
    <? if (isset($storages[$row['key']])): ?>
    <tr>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td><?=$storages[$row['key']]?></td>
    </tr>
    <? endif ?>
  <? endforeach ?>
<? endif ?>
```